# Open and save base64 encoded image data URI in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, base64

From several posts I've seen, I am trying this

```
x = Base64.decode64("data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....")
File.open('test.png','wb') {|file| file.write x}
```

But then I can't open the image with a viewer, do I have to do something more?

Comment: Pardon my intrusion: just in case you arrived here (like I did) looking for base64 PNG *encode* oneliner in ruby: `"data:image/png;base64,"+Base64.strict_encode64(File.read("test.png"))` -- carry on. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to decode the `'data:image/png;base64,'` prefix as Base64 data; that prefix is perfectly valid Base64 data but it is not the Base64 representation of a PNG file. The result is that your `test.png` file contains a bunch of nonsense followed by some bits that actually are a PNG file. Strip off the data URL prefix before decoding the PNG:

```
data_url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...."
png      = Base64.decode64(data_url['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
File.open('test.png', 'wb') { |f| f.write(png) }
```

Comment: How would you detect several formats?, I did `data_url.match(/data:(.*);base64,(.*)/)` to get the encode type, file format, and image data, but I am not sure if this could cause performance issue when string is big.

Comment: @juanpastas: Anchor the regex at the beginning and use simple string operations to strip off the prefix. And you might want to be a bit more specific about what the MIME type looks like.

Comment: MIME types I am handling are: image/png, image/jpg

Comment: Thank you, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: @AdrianMann What do you mean by *elegant*? There are many ways to chop up a string and Base64-decode part of it but they're all variations on this.

Comment: If it's in Rails and you know the MIME type, you can do `Base64.decode64( data_url.remove('data:image/png;base64,') )`

Comment: @xjlin0 That's roughly equivalent to using `String#[]` with a Range argument but probably clearer if you're not used to `.. -1` ranges.

Answer (score 6):

mu_is_too_short answer is pretty close, but it assumes that base64 stream will contain PNG data. This is not always the case so I suggest to use mime types library to establish correct file extension:

```
REGEXP = /\Adata:([-\w]+\/[-\w\+\.]+)?;base64,(.*)/m

data_uri_parts = data_url.match(REGEXP) || []
extension = MIME::Types[data_uri_parts[1]].first.preferred_extension
file_name = "myfilename.#{extension}"

File.open(file_name, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(Base64.decode64(data_uri_parts[2]))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Regexp`, you can also make use of the simple [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-index) method.

> Returns the index of the **first** occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str. Returns nil if not found.

If you have a reasonably sane data source (like JavaScript's `.toDataURL()` on a `canvas`), you can rely on the fact that common mimetypes will not contain commas.

```
dataURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...."
start = dataURL.index(',') + 1                   # .index used here
x = Base64.decode64 dataURL[start..-1]
File.open('test.png','wb') {|file| file.write x}
```

If you're working with a free-form user file upload, beware that a few uncommon mime types do contain commas (e.g.: `text/x-java-source,java`). You can use the more conservative:

```
start = dataURL.index(';base64,') + 8
```

If you don't know if you have unprefixed base64 or data URL base64, you can use `#index` as  test:

```
start = dataURL.index ';base64,'
dataURL = dataURL[(start+8)..-1] if start
x = Base64.decode64 dataURL
```

Answer (score 0):

that's a little script about how to open base64 image,vacio.txt is the file when i have the base64 text.

```
require 'base64'
entry="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQE....."
File.open("vacio.txt","r") do |fichero|
 while linea=fichero.gets
  regex=/(data:image\/\D*\d*,)/
  m=regex.match(linea)
  png=Base64.decode64(linea[m.to_s.length .. -1])
  File.open('test.jpeg','wb'){|f|f.write(png)}
 end
end
```